# cakePHP no longer giving debug information

Tags: cakephp

I just upgraded from cakePHP 1.2.8 to 1.3.5 and now the debug information (that from the level set in the Core) does not seem to be doing anything anymore. No matter what level I set 'debug' to, it doesn't print the queries at the bottom of the screen.

Any idea what I may have done wrong?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you need to include this element in your default layout (or anywhere, really):

```
<?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?>
```

See:

http://book.cakephp.org/view/1567/Model-Databases-and-Datasources
&
http://book.cakephp.org/view/1561/Migrating-from-CakePHP-1-2-to-1-3

Answer (score 1):

I recommend the use of [DebugKit](http://github.com/cakephp/debug_kit), it provides more debug information than the basic core function and doesn't interfere with your layout because it adds a mini toolbar positioned as absolute at the top of your page.