# CakePHP Login Layout

Tags: php, cakephp

I created a login view for my `Employee controller`, but when the login view renders, it shows up as a plain white page (not the layout from my default.ctp).

I tried calling `$this->layout = 'default';` from the login action,
but it sounds like that code will not execute until after the view has posted.

**controllers/employee_controller.php**

```
function login() {
    $this->layout = 'default';
}
```

**views/layouts/default.ctp**

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title><?php echo $title_for_layout; ?></title>
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href='<?php echo "css".DS."cake.generic.css" ?>' />
    </head>
    <body>
    <div id="parentDiv">
        <div id="menu">
            <div id="messages">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="header">
            <?= $this->element('search'); ?>
        </div>
        <div id="content">
            <?php echo $content_for_layout; ?>
        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

**views/employees/login.ctp**

```
<?= debug($this); ?>
<div>
    <div style="border: black solid 1px">
        <?php
        /*
         * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
         * and open the template in the editor.
         */
        echo $this->Form->create('Employee', array('url' => array('controller' => 'employees', 'action' => 'login')));
        echo $this->Form->input('username');
        echo $this->Form->input('password');
        echo $this->Form->submit('Login');
        echo $this->Form->end();
        ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: have you made the view, you can check the error by editing core.php file and set debug mode to 2

Comment: @nik, thank you for your suggestions.  Yes, there is a view (I know this for a fact is working because I see the view rendering with the login text boxes and button) and debug isn't telling me anything (I have debug on 2).

Comment: Oh! I can't tell the problem unless taking a look to the files. In my case I never mentioned the layout when it is default.

Comment: I'm confused - you say you get a blank page then you say you can see the form! Are you talking about a post-login view?

Comment: BTW, if you're using CakePHP 1.3 and have debug set to 2, you will not see database debug unless you add <?php echo $this->element('sql_dump'); ?> somewhere in a layout or view - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4063594/cakephp-no-longer-giving-debug-information/4063667#4063667

Comment: @Leo - I think he meant that a blank layout is being rendered.
@Benny - Showing us some code would be helpful. Is this happening for only /employees/login?

Comment: post code of your login action

Comment: My login action is simply $this->layout = "default";

Comment: Add `debug($this);` to the top of your login view (e.g. `app/views/employees/login.ctp`). This will show you the state of the View object as your login view loads, and should provide you a bunch of good troubleshooting information: the view and layout that have *actually* been used, the variables available in the view, etc.

Comment: Looks like it has the right layout value, but nothing for the path if that matters? [layout] => default
    [layoutPath] => //empty

Comment: Check your PHP/web server error log. If **nothing at all** is rendered, that usually means there's some error before even the Cake error handler could take over.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your code, this is most certainly due to CSS path being incorrect.  Can you replace the line calling your stylesheet with the code I've given below? 
`<?php print $html->css('cake.generic.css'); ?>`

Comment: the .htaccess files all match line for line with the book.  I'm not sure what you mean by "forcing the database to load"?  See my edit for more code.

Comment: Also - Use the helpers provided to you and this isn't an issue.